# How to work with Azure AD external login with ASP.NET Idenity in Identity Server4

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory, identityserver4

I follow below article to get work with asp.net identity in IdenityServer4:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html

Now i want to add Azure AD as external Idp :

```
 services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();


        services.AddAuthentication()
           .AddOpenIdConnect("AAD", "Azure Active Directory", options =>
           {
               options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
               options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;
               options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
               options.ClientId = "xxxxxxx";
               options.Scope.Add("openid");
               options.Scope.Add("profile");
               options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
               {
                   ValidateIssuer = false
               };
               options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
           });
```

But when i debug my application ==> redirect to identity server==>click AAD login . I notice when i reach the Azure AD username/password page ,my client app stops , so after enter the credentials and consent , i will stay on the identity server page . Can anyone provides some suggestions ?

Comment: maybe this sample can help you: https://github.com/mclark1129/IdentityServer4.Samples/tree/master/AzureAd_CustomStateDataFormat

Comment: @MartinBrandl , thanks ,i have try the solution , but the codes shows error , the function is obsolte

Comment: Maybe you have to set the options.RepsonseType property in your example

Comment: How about the configuration in Azure AD? How is Identity Server configured there? What OAuth2 flow are you using?

Comment: @ChaimZonnenberg , Azure AD config is correct . Identity Server configured is provide as above shown . I use the hybrid flow .

Comment: @MartinBrandl ,set "options.Scope.Add("openid");" but the same problem

Comment: Then put a breakpoint in the 'ExternalLoginCallback' in the AccountController. Check if all claims are mapped/provided correctly for your client app.

Comment: @ChaimZonnenberg , at Azure AD login page the client app already stop ,never hit the ExternalLoginCallback function .

Comment: If your client app terminates when browsing to AAD, it might be debugger/environment related. Does/Can the client app provide logging why it stops? What if you run the client app in IIS?

Comment: @ChaimZonnenberg ,but if i removed the AAD login part , the client app works fine , i think it should be some extra configuration/codes if AAD is required .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interesting part is when i turn to use chrome to start my client app in visual studio , the client app is not stopped anymore  . Quite strange and not to find a explanation .

Answer (score 0):

I see you commented out your Microsoft Authority URL, like it is specific to your company.  I have Azure AD external login configured for my company's auth and I just have to call https://login.microsoftonline.com/common.

Also, if it is redirecting fine to Microsoft's site and not returning back to your Auth server, you probably do not have something set up properly in the ExternalLogin function in your controller.

It should look something like this:

```
var props = new AuthenticationProperties()
{
    RedirectUri = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback"),
    Items =
    {
        { "returnUrl", returnUrl },
        { "scheme", provider },
    }
};
return Challenge(props, provider);
```

Where provider would be your 'AAD'.